# Racket macro that generates a nested module error

Tags: macros, racket, hygiene

While experimenting with racket's macros, I stumbled into a definition that wasn't at first obvious to me why it was rejected. The code is short and otherwise is probably useless, but is as follows:

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax (go stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id)
     #'(module mod racket
         (define it id))]
    ))
(go 'dummy)
```

The complaint is `quote: unbound identifier; also, no #%app syntax transformer...`
If I manually inline `(define it id)` to `(define it 'dummy)` then it works.
I had a hunch that `'` ie. `quote` of `(go 'dummy)` that is bound by `#lang racket` is not recognized as the same binding within the submodule mod even though syntactically it is the same sequence of letters. If I strip 'dummy of all lexical context by round tripping as follows:

```
(with-syntax ([ok (datum->syntax #f (syntax->datum #'id))])
```

below the pattern match `(_ id)` and replace definition of `it` with `(define it ok)` then all is good again.

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax (go stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id)
     (with-syntax ([ok (datum->syntax #f (syntax->datum #'id))])
       #'(module mod racket
           (define it ok)))]
    ))
(go 'dummy)
```

I presume that my dilemma was caused by the hygiene system. However, is there a more direct solution to convince racket compiler that these identifiers, ie. `quote` are really the same without this boilerplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that you insert for `id` in:

```
(module mod racket
  (define it id))
```

is going to be evaluated in the context of the module.
Therefore the syntactic context id id needs to be the same as 
the context of the submodule.

You describe one way of removing existing context. Here is another:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax racket/base))

(define-syntax (go stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id)
     (with-syntax ([id (syntax->datum #'id)])
       #'(module mod racket
           (provide it)
           (define it id)))]))

(go 42)
(require (submod "." mod))
it
```

In most macros it is a good thing that context is preserved, so
having to "boiler plate" to remove it seems okay to me.

Of course, if you experience to much boiler plate then write
a macro that inserts the boiler plate for you :-)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Just out of curiosity, could there be another solution where one could directly convince racket that the top level #lang racket module and the nested module with racket expander are the same? For example, there is a namespace-attach-module function that convinces racket that a top level require of some specific module and namespace-require of the same module are really one and the same when using eval. This is what you have shown in your answer to another question on Jun 17th.

Comment: If you want the same scope for your expressions, then why put them in the submodule in the first place?

Comment: I suppose the problem is indeed contrived. The only idea I have where this may be useful is when the nested module contains only a subset of the top level bindings such that you can easily reject certain expressions. I'm not convinced this would warrant a new API facility.

Comment: It would be better to use `strip-context` here from `syntax/strip-context`, since that will preserve source locations.